# htaccess replace underscores with dashes

Tags: .htaccess

I wants to replace underscore with dash in my website URL. something like this:

from: http://example.com/test/test_a_a_a_a.php
to: http://example.com/test/test-a-a-a-a.php

but I don't wants to change file name which is this: test_a_a_a_a.php (file name should be stays same I just wants to write rule in htaccess not anything in file even)

I tried lots of things but its saying page not found (404) error. so please help.

Thanks,
Aj

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for that in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(test)/([^_]*)_+(.*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```